# axlsx conditional formatting using a dynamic range

Tags: axlsx

I need to apply conditional formatting on a dynamic range by axlsx. That is, in the example below, replace the 'A2:A10' by something like

```
'A2:A' & sheet.rows.last
```

as it would work in excel VBA

```
red = styles.add_style(:bg_color=> 'FFFF0000', :type => :dxf)
# Apply conditional formatting to range A2:A10 in the worksheet
sheet.add_conditional_formatting('A2:A10', { :type => :cellIs,
                                          :operator => :equal,
                                          :formula => "1",
                                          :dxfId => red,
                                          :priority => 1 })
```

I studied the documentation and tried some versions without success.
I'm not very familiar to axlsx, but want to extend functionality of an existing project. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've now made a workaround, which fits my needs:

Comment: by adding an additional dump rule with higher priority and `:stopIfTrue => 1`. Nevertheless, I leave the question open to show the need for flexibility in the range determination.